# Randomly shuffling torch tensor

Tags: shuffle, tensor, torch

I have a tensor of batch size of 64. Each sample in the batch is of shape `[4, 300]`. So, shape of my batch is `[64, 4, 300]`. I want to randomly shuffle the elements of the batch. In other words, I want to shuffle all 64 `[4, 300]` tensors. How can I do this? The resulting tensor will obviously be of shape `[64, 4, 300]`, but all the 64 rows of shape `[4, 300]`, will be ordered differently.

Answer (score 8):

```
indexes = torch.randperm(data.shape[0])
data = data[indexes]
```